# Playwright (Python) performance on WSL2 is much slower than on Win11 — any fix?

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, playwright, playwright-python

I use Playwright (with Python 3.11) for scraping workflow (on a Windows 11 machine) and recently started moving towards all development work inside WSL2. I've noticed Playwright headless and head-ed browser performance (across all the browsers) seems to be abysmal on WSL2 compared to on Windows.

Typical workflow:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

... # other code

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://benjamintseng.com/') # just picking my Wordpress blog as an example
    ... # other code
```

Leads to a timeout on the `page.goto` command at 30 seconds (as per default). When I load this with `headless=False`, I can see that DOM elements have loaded but the browser just doesn't ever finish loading (the "loading loop") just keeps going. The network tab in the inspector appears empty. I didn't see anything obvious in the console tab.

When I run identical code on Python on Windows 11, there is no delay or timeout.

Is this just "overhead" from "Linux emulation" that comes with WSL that I need to live with (but shouldn't be there if I run this on a full Linux server) or is there a fix / change I can make? I'd really like to keep everything in WSL for local work (allows me to combine the Windows apps I'm familiar with, not to mention some I need for work) with Linux command-line/development tools.

Comment: What Playwright version(s) are you using? Is this for all sites, or just the one shared? I generally advise folks to use `page.goto(url, wait_until="domcontentloaded")` which is faster than the default `"load"` event.

Comment: Actually, there's an even faster version: `page.goto(url, wait_until="commit")` worth trying.

Comment: Playwright 1.42.0 — it's across most websites. `domcontentloaded` also times out. `commit` returns almost instantly but doesn't resolve the issue that ultimately the page takes forever to finish loading (and I don't know when the DOM is sufficiently well-loaded to carry out some of my scraping ops)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Locators auto-wait, so they handle knowing when the DOM is sufficiently loaded. It's on an element-by-element basis. You can also speed things up by blocking images, stylesheets, scripts and assets you don't need. In any case, I don't think there's enough info to reproduce extreme slowness in WSL here but hopefully someone can help. You might try downgrading to a Playwright version that's a year or so old just to see if it makes a difference. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas.